# Extract all possible field paths from Java Protocol Buffers

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a set of complied Java Protocol Buffers. I need to extract all possible fields from it, can I do it w/o knowing structure of a Protocol Buffer in advance?

Imagine I have a message

```
message Person {
  required string name = 1;
  required int32 id = 2;
  optional string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    required string number = 1;
    optional PhoneType type = 2 [default = HOME];
    required PhoneLocation location = 3;
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phones = 4;
}

message PhoneLocation {
  required string name = 1;
}
```

I need something that will print for me ([*] stands for repeated field)

```
Person.name
Person.id
Person.email
person.phones[*]
person.phones[*].number
person.phones[*].type
person.phones[*].location.name
```

I have only java class, how can I do it?

Comment: You could use the `Descriptor` associated with `Person` (`Person.getDescriptor()`) to find the list of fields.  I can't actually tell if you just want to print the names of the fields, or their value, but you could do it either way with the descriptor.

Comment: You have to specify something in your question. Are you starting from a .proto file? Are you starting from a Java .class file? Or what do you mean by "without knowing the structure of the protobuf in advance"? [I feel that the above comment by Louis works if you have the Person structure, but I'm not sure, but if that's the case then can we assume you start from that?]